# Does changing VLAN on a interface change the IP of device conn to that interface?

Tags: vlan, ipv4

A device was in wrong VLAN (VLAN 10) with IP address `10.202.55.11` and Gateway IP address `10.202.55.1`, but the device should be on VLAN 11 (IP range-`10.202.48.0/24`).

Will changing the VLAN of that device interface issue a new IP address to that device in the VLAN 11 range (`10.202.48.0/24`)? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, a specific VLAN is associated with a specific IP subnet. So essentially, changing the VLAN association changes the IP address. Assuming you require routing between the VLANs/subnet, there's no other way.

However, the IP doesn't change itself and is not assigned by the VLAN. It's either statically assigned or issued by a DHCP server serving that VLAN.

Comment: Thanks @Zac67. It makes sense. There is IP-Helper configured on the routed VLAN interface which fetch the request from the DHCP server and assign it to the device connected to that interface.

Answer (score 0):

If setup is  with  DHCP configuration  . According to Vlan configuration on interfàce . IP address will allocate from particularly DHCP scope to interface connected to devices .

If we are assigning IP address statically  to interface connected to device . Then correct static ip address need to be configured on interfàce connected devices with reference to Vlan passed on interfàce .

If wrong ip address is assigned then connectivity will fail..